# window.setInterval Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval

I am trying to "animate" objects by using the setInterval code, but I am having one of 3 problems;
- Nothing happens
- Whatever is coded seems to make the change but then stops (maybe doing it once)
- The div coded seems to disappear off screen

Does anyone know what is wrong? I typed `console.log("Text");` and it was running fine. (Also, I apologize, but I have no idea how to format on this website)

```
var everyFrame=function()
{
skyRed=skyRed+1;
skyGreen=skyGreen-0.3;
skyBlue=skyBlue-0.7;
orangeFishMoveDown=orangeFishMoveDown+0.025;
orangeFishMoveRight=orangeFishMoveRight+.05;

sky.style.backgroundColor='rgb('+skyRed+','+skyGreen+','+skyBlue+')';
orangeFish.style.top=orangeFishMoveDown+'px';
orangeFish.style.left=orangeFishMoveRight+'px';
};

window.setInterval(everyFrame, 33);
```

Comment: Your formatting is fine :)

Comment: Then if the formatting is fine, would something else be wrong? Is chrome not working with intervals well?

Comment: The issue is likely to do with `skyRed=skyRed+1`etc..

Where are these variables initialised?

Comment: Check your console log. Are there any errors?

Comment: @Denno it is likely that they are global variables initialized somewhere else.

Comment: @iPhoenix I don't see any errors anywhere. I'm still kind of new to this so I don't quite know where to look, but I checked all the tabs I could think of on Google Chrome Developer Tools and nothing seemed to show any errors.
@Denno The variables are defined earlier in my code. For example, skyRed is defined as `var skyRed='0';`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable as a number, not as a string

```
var skyRed = 0;
```

otherwise, it will be concatenated as a string, not added, in `skyRed=skyRed+1;`

See here:

```js
var skyRed = '0';
var skyRed1 = 0;
console.log('wrong:' + (skyRed + 1), 'correct: ' + (skyRed1 + 1));
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I don't know why I thought that it had to be a string.